# Send multiple requests using one "sendPost"function

Tags: java

How can i use "sendPost Function", Instead of using more than one "sendPost function" for different requests in NodeJs ?

like this Example,I do 2 sendPost function to send 2 requests.
But the code itself is in the two functions with little change, so I want a way to do one "sendPost" function for both requests.

////////sign up

```
    public static void sendPOST1(String POST_PARAMS) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Sending http");
    URL obj = new URL(POST_URL_SU);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setConnectTimeout(50000); // 5 seconds
    con.setReadTimeout(50000); // 5 seconds
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    byte[] outputBytesArray = POST_PARAMS.getBytes();
    os.write(outputBytesArray);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        // Here it read line line 
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Res: " + response.toString());
         } else {
        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
        }
        }
```

////////Login

```
       public static void sendPOST2(String POST_PARAMS) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending http");
        URL obj = new URL(POST_URL_LI);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setConnectTimeout(50000); // 5 seconds
        con.setReadTimeout(50000); // 5 seconds
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream(); 
         byte[] outputBytesArray = POST_PARAMS.getBytes();  
         os.write(outputBytesArray);
         os.flush();
         os.close();
         int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
         System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);
         if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
         String inputLine;
         StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
          }
         in.close();
         System.out.println("Res: " + response.toString());
         } else {
         System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
         System.out.println("POST request not worked");
         }
         }
```

Comment: I edit it.I set an example

Comment: Your code appears to be Java, not node.js. I have edited the tags to reflect his.

Comment: Yes , I'm Sorry .
This is Java

Comment: I suggest you format the code. Using correct indentation and writing empty lines for separate parts of the code helps the reader to understand the examples.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will do it the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single function `sendPost()` that takes a URL parameter:

```
public static void sendPost(String url, String POST_PARAMS) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending http");
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setConnectTimeout(50000); // 5 seconds
        con.setReadTimeout(50000); // 5 seconds
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream(); 
         byte[] outputBytesArray = POST_PARAMS.getBytes();  
         os.write(outputBytesArray);
         os.flush();
         os.close();
         int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
         System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);
         if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
         String inputLine;
         StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
          }
         in.close();
         System.out.println("Res: " + response.toString());
         } else {
         System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
         System.out.println("POST request not worked");
         }
         }
```

In fact, I suggest you break this function into several smaller functions that do simple tasks.

Comment: Thank you I used the solution that you wrote, and my problem was solved.
But Can you tell me how can i make this code divided into simple tasks, as you suggested,Can you Make it ?

Comment: @MarioNelban7 When I am writing a new program, I will write the steps in words to describe what the program does. Each step or sentence generally represents a function that I can write in code. So for example here I see two steps: 1) Send POST request 2) Process response. The code for these two steps can be split into two separate functions.

Comment: Thank you very much.